# why register button is not registering usename and password?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

while making login/register components through hook, i made separate functions with hook for Login, Logout, register and users.

since hook is easier for me, after excuting npm start, no error is showing.

**App.js:**

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import Users from './Users'


const App=()=> {

        const [user,setUser]=useState('')
          return (  
                <div style={{padding:8}} className="container">
                    <Users user={user} setUser={setUser}/>
                    <br/>
                    <hr/>
                   </div>
            );
        }

export default App
```

**Login.js:**

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
const Login=(setUser)=>{
    const [username,setUsername]=useState('');

    const handleUserName=(event)=>{
        setUsername(event.target.value)
    }
    return(
    <form onSubmit={e => { e.preventDefault(); setUsername(username) }}>
      <label htmlFor="login-username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" value={username} onChange={handleUserName} name="login-username" id="login-username" />
      <label htmlFor="login-password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" name="login-password" id="login-password" />
      <input type="submit" value="Login" disabled={username.length === 0} />
    </form>
    )
}

export default Login
```

**Logout.js:**

```
import React from 'react'

const Logout=(user,setUser)=>{
return(
    <form onSubmit={e=>{e.preventDefault();setUser('')}}>
        Logged in As:<b>{user}</b>
        <input type="submit" value="Logout"></input>
    </form>
)
}
export default Logout
```

**Register.js:**

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
const Register=(setUser)=>{
    const [username,setUsername]=useState('')
    const [password,setPassword]=useState('')
    const [passwordRepeat,setPasswordRepeat]=useState('')

    const handleUserName=(event)=>{
        setUsername(event.target.value)
    }

    const handlePassword=(event)=>{
        setPassword(event.target.value)
    }
    const handlePasswordRepeat=(event)=>{
        setPasswordRepeat(event.target.value)
    }

    return(
        <form onSubmit={e=>{e.preventDefault();setUsername(username)}}>
            <label htmlFor="register-username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" value={username} onChange={handleUserName} name="register-username" id="register-username"/>
            <br/>
            <label htmlFor="register-password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" value={password} onChange={handlePassword} name="register-password" id="register-password"/>
            <br/>
            <label htmlFor="register-password-repeat">repeat password:</label>
            <input type="password" value={passwordRepeat} onChange={handlePasswordRepeat} name="register-password-repeat" id="register-password-repeat"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Register" disabled={username.length===0||password.length===0||password!==passwordRepeat}/>
        </form>
    )

}
export default Register
```

**Users.js:**

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import Login from './Login'
import Logout from './Logout'
import Register from './Register'
const User=()=>{
    const {user,setUser}=useState('');

        if (user){
            return <Logout user={user} setUser={setUser}/>
        } else {
            return (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <Login setUser={setUser}/>
                    <br/>
                    <Register setUser={setUser}/> 
                </React.Fragment>
            )
        }

} 
export default User;
```

there is no error showing but when i try to register the username, it's showing **TypeError: setUser is not a function reacjs** in register.js in the line `<form onSubmit={e=>{e.preventDefault();setUser(username)}}>`

i am very new to reactJS and i know i did some wrong in calling setUser....but it seems like it's react's very own function.

if you give me any solution with explanation it will be a good way to learn. i would like to modife the codes and write these in my own understandable way.

thanx in advance

Comment: pass function in props and execute your setUser in that function

Comment: You should do: `const [user,setUser]=useState('')`

Comment: well you're getting this error because you've setUsername as an action function in your hook and while submitting a form you're calling setUser which is no where in your register.js. so in your form submit use setUsername instead of setUser

check my answer

Comment: i did it because i thought username should be kept as user....after doing this i would like to do user's list to make a full CRUD of my own. any way, i tried your way setting setUserName but register button click won't show any change

Comment: If you need list then you should have blank [] in your initial state object instead of '', otherwise what happens is everytime it will overwrite the registration.

note. you must have to use [] braces while declaring hooks instead of { }

Comment: Hi @ali I think you are getting a error when clicks on logout because there is no setuser function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting a error when clicks on logout because there is no setuser function .You can Handle this by passing actions via props

[Here is the working example from your code](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-meadow-7vopm)

Comment: thanx man...... i was thinking about the absence something in Register.js and at that moment i saw your post.... you wrote exactly what i thought about and works fine...thanx again

Answer (score 0):

because of this string: `const {user,setUser}=useState('')`
setUser is `undefined`;
when you try to call it you get error because undefined is not a function.

you should type:
`const [user,setUser]=useState('');`

Comment: i fixed it but problem is still the same....register button is not registering anything or showing any error now....problem is not going away

Answer (score 0):

you're getting this error because you've setUsername as an action function in your hook and while submitting a form you're calling setUser which is no where in your register.js. so in your form submit use setUsername instead of setUser.

```
Register.js

import React,{useState} from 'react'
const Register=(setUser)=>{
    const [username,setUsername]=useState('') // here : you've serUsername
    const [password,setPassword]=useState('')
    const [passwordRepeat,setPasswordRepeat]=useState('')

    const handleUserName=(event)=>{
        setUsername(event.target.value)
    }

    const handlePassword=(event)=>{
        setPassword(event.target.value)
    }
    const handlePasswordRepeat=(event)=>{
        setPasswordRepeat(event.target.value)
    }

    return(
        <form onSubmit={e=>{e.preventDefault(); **setUsername(username)**}}>
            <label htmlFor="register-username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" value={username} onChange={handleUserName} name="register-username" id="register-username"/>
            <br/>
            <label htmlFor="register-password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" value={password} onChange={handlePassword} name="register-password" id="register-password"/>
            <br/>
            <label htmlFor="register-password-repeat">repeat password:</label>
            <input type="password" value={passwordRepeat} onChange={handlePasswordRepeat} name="register-password-repeat" id="register-password-repeat"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Register" disabled={username.length===0||password.length===0||password!==passwordRepeat}/>
        </form>
    )

}
export default Register
```

also in your login.js file you made same mistake correct it as below;

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
const Login=(setUser)=>{
    const [username,setUsername]=useState(''); // here same mistake

    const handleUserName=(event)=>{
        setUsername(event.target.value)
    }
    return(
    <form onSubmit={e => { e.preventDefault(); **setUsername(username)** }}> 
      <label htmlFor="login-username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" value={username} onChange={handleUserName} name="login-username" id="login-username" />
      <label htmlFor="login-password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" name="login-password" id="login-password" />
      <input type="submit" value="Login" disabled={username.length === 0} />
    </form>
    )
}

export default Login
```

Comment: i tried it changing both setUsername, but this time error is not showing and register button is working or registering my username password. which comes to the second problem, in Users.js i used if...else.... why is not working....? and why it's not registering?

Comment: @ali, in your users.js first remove { } and add [ ] instead of it. and please show the error which is coming from users.js

Comment: there is no error showing.  according to dev tool console:[DOM] Input elements should have autocomplete attributes (suggested: "current-password"):  <input type=​"password" name=​"login-password" id=​"login-password">​
localhost/:1 [DOM] Input elements should have autocomplete attributes (suggested: "new-password"): <input type=​"password" name=​"register-password" id=​"register-password" value=​"******" aria-autocomplete=​"list">​

Comment: that's an suggestion / warning.

Comment: nope...i am pressing register in google chrome and maxthon....but it just not showing Logged is as: Ali according to Logout.js. another thing: for onHandling preventHandling i used setUser. but according to your suggestion i am using setUsername.... i just wanted it setUser so that later i can use it in CRUD backend registration